# Finding all squares within range, and finding the shortest path to the selected square

Tags: graph-algorithm, path-finding

I have a grid system with characters and obstacles, and I need to 1) find out all the squares on the grid that are within a range, say 2 steps from the current location 2) then find the shortest path to a square that is selected from the ones that are within the range.

E.g. if I had a 6 x 6 grid with # being obstacles and I wanted to get from A to B:

```
. . . . . .
. A . . . .
. # # . . .
. B . . . .
. . . . . .
. . . . . .
```

So I would first find the squares / points on the grid within say 5 steps from A:

```
x x x x x x
x A x x x x
x # # x x x
x B x x x .
x x . x . .
x . . . . .
```

And then if it is true that B is in those points, find the shortest path there, in this case from the left side of the obstacles. Bad example in the sense that there is no other option, but there could well be if the range was higher. And the range is not something I know beforehand.

```
. . . . . .
o A . . . .
o # # . . .
o B . . . .
. . . . . .
. . . . . .
```

I could do the first part, finding all points within range, with BFS. And maybe the second one with Dijkstra's. But is this the most efficient way of doing it? Is there maybe a better way to do both somewhat similar things with one algorithm or less bruteforcing?

It will be part of the game where I first highlight the squares where one could move and then once a square is selected the character moves there. I'm using Python and Pygame if that matters.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Are you sure you dont want the algorithm for shortest path from A to B?

Comment: In the second part yes, I will need that result. But I also first need to get all the squares within range. And yes it is an XY problem, it's basically just simple cartesian coordinates.